# Lost access to LVM cached volume

Tags: linux, lvm

I don't normally ask for help with Linux, preferring to figure things out for myself, but this time I'm really stuck and I don't know where to turn for help.

About a year ago, I added lvmcache to one of my LVs as an experiment. A few days ago I upgraded my kernel (yum update), and after a reboot I'm unable to access that LV any more. It has important data on it that I'd really like to get back.

I have two volume groups, SSD and Rust:

- SSD is a software (MD) raid1 array of two 1Tb NVMe devices.
- Rust is a software (MD) raid5 array of four 10Tb hard disks.

For various reasons I didn't want the SSD to be entirely a cache and not usable for anything else, so I setup LVM on it and created LVs for the root filesystem, LXC containers, etc. These are the LVs that I have:

```
$ sudo lvs
  WARNING: Device for PV 0hAsMD-LsJf-YsiF-iQ0B-tI23-8hso-cRP93L not found or rejected by a filter.
  Couldn't find device with uuid 0hAsMD-LsJf-YsiF-iQ0B-tI23-8hso-cRP93L.
  LV           VG   Attr       LSize   Pool    Origin         Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  Backups      Rust -wi-a-----   1.00t                                                               
  Dxxxxx       Rust -wi-a-----   3.00t                                                               
  Microserver  Rust -wi-a-----   5.00t                                                               
  NAS          Rust -wi-a-----   5.00t                                                               
  Photos       Rust Cwi---C-p-   3.00t [Cache] [Photos_corig]                                        
  Rescued      Rust -wi-a-----   6.00t                                                               
  Video        Rust -wi-a-----   2.00t                                                               
  CentOS7_Root SSD  -wi-ao----  50.00g                                                               
  Containers   SSD  -wi-ao---- 200.00g                                                               
  MD_Journal   SSD  -wi-ao----  16.00g                                                               
  Rust_Cache   SSD  -wi-a----- 256.00g                                                               
  home         SSD  -wi-ao---- 100.00g
```

Photos is the inaccessible cached LV. The setup was a bit tricky because lvmcache insists that the origin and cache LVs live in the same VG, and mine do not (one is on Rust, the other is on SSD). I got around this by creating the cache volume on SSD, then formatting it as a PV, and adding that PV to the Rust group. These are the commands that I ran to set it up a year ago:

```
# Create a cache volume (LV) on the SSD device
lvcreate -L 256G -n Rust_Cache /dev/SSD
# Format that volume as a PV:
pvcreate /dev/SSD/Rust_Cache
# Add it to the Rust VG:
vgextend /dev/Rust /dev/SSD/Rust_Cache
# Create the cache data volume on it:
lvcreate -L 100G -n Cache Rust /dev/SSD/Rust_Cache
# Create the cache meta volume on it:
lvcreate -L 4G -n Cache_Meta Rust /dev/SSD/Rust_Cache
# Combine them into a cache pool:
lvconvert --type cache-pool /dev/Rust/Cache --poolmetadata /dev/Rust/Cache_Meta
# Set that pool as the cache of the Photos LV:
lvconvert --type cache /dev/Rust/Photos --cachepool /dev/Rust/Cache
```

I think the problem is related to the error message shown above:

```
  WARNING: Device for PV 0hAsMD-LsJf-YsiF-iQ0B-tI23-8hso-cRP93L not found or rejected by a filter.
  Couldn't find device with uuid 0hAsMD-LsJf-YsiF-iQ0B-tI23-8hso-cRP93L.
```

This is the UUID of the cache PV (/dev/SSD/Rust_Cache), at least according to `/etc/lvm/backup/Rust`. I can't confirm it because it refuses to `pvdisplay`:

```
$ sudo pvdisplay /dev/SSD/Rust_Cache 
  Failed to find device for physical volume "/dev/SSD/Rust_Cache".
  WARNING: Device for PV 0hAsMD-LsJf-YsiF-iQ0B-tI23-8hso-cRP93L not found or rejected by a filter.
  Couldn't find device with uuid 0hAsMD-LsJf-YsiF-iQ0B-tI23-8hso-cRP93L.
```

I don't think the device is really "not found", because the other volumes on SSD are working fine, and they all share a single PV. I think it must be filtered out by whatever magic is "hiding" the cache volumes and origin volume within LVM, but I don't know what that is.

I'm prepared to accept that I may have lost some data on this volume if I can't recover the cache, however I don't want to lose it completely. It's hopefully all backed up on S3, but given the volume of data and number of small files, it's hard to be sure. Any suggestions about what I can do to make it accessible again?

`vgchange -ay` refuses to activate it, but hints that I could force it, so that may be one option if there's no way to recover the cache:

```
$ sudo vgchange -ay
  WARNING: Device for PV 0hAsMD-LsJf-YsiF-iQ0B-tI23-8hso-cRP93L not found or rejected by a filter.
  Couldn't find device with uuid 0hAsMD-LsJf-YsiF-iQ0B-tI23-8hso-cRP93L.
  Refusing activation of partial LV Rust/Photos.  Use '--activationmode partial' to override.
  6 logical volume(s) in volume group "Rust" now active
  5 logical volume(s) in volume group "SSD" now active
```

Output of `blkid` on all devices, as requested:

```
[sudo] password for chris: 
/dev/mapper/SSD-Rust_Cache: UUID="0hAsMD-LsJf-YsiF-iQ0B-tI23-8hso-cRP93L" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/nvme0n1: PTTYPE="gpt" 
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="29970b49-140d-6862-786d-f33b5edcab6d" UUID_SUB="7cfe4ba4-3062-3ebb-a2a3-0b3f119e2ccc" LABEL="blackbox.qwarx.com:pv00" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="92abf126-4192-4a7d-8381-85a1ad1b2eaf" 
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="a42550e8-adac-3f6e-68ef-41bddb5fa54c" UUID_SUB="cd19178f-2428-2442-0c60-99c4abff3c59" LABEL="blackbox.qwarx.com:Boot" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="3e5c4c02-4483-48fd-82eb-6973bea5674f" 
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="1d3395dc-7e7c-bf69-7e51-e49fcb2d085d" UUID_SUB="ede510d6-1468-b9a9-b4af-d8b77af5cd4e" LABEL="blackbox.qwarx.com:EFI" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="81fdb48b-7cd8-4e55-8358-3f3f8aee1800" 
/dev/nvme1n1: PTTYPE="gpt" 
/dev/nvme1n1p1: UUID="29970b49-140d-6862-786d-f33b5edcab6d" UUID_SUB="dc5e4a8f-3281-cf7e-55a6-b95924872cc6" LABEL="blackbox.qwarx.com:pv00" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="ef1a40a2-c8b2-4428-ad29-fdc1b2640634" 
/dev/nvme1n1p2: UUID="a42550e8-adac-3f6e-68ef-41bddb5fa54c" UUID_SUB="54dab930-9e4e-1009-8618-eb100d5de05c" LABEL="blackbox.qwarx.com:Boot" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="26a6252a-871c-4768-916c-1ce038511874" 
/dev/nvme1n1p3: UUID="1d3395dc-7e7c-bf69-7e51-e49fcb2d085d" UUID_SUB="e752061b-8410-46fa-c871-04b16b0844bf" LABEL="blackbox.qwarx.com:EFI" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="d16924c1-96b3-4f9f-bef0-8e5ce4402bf0" 
/dev/md127: LABEL="Boot" UUID="da2c2ddd-af52-4dfe-92ac-9775cc015234" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/md126: UUID="AKAeOG-fIdp-DKl7-mDiI-LHcH-y09B-3Vxjqw" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/sdb: UUID="653729f4-efb2-af46-dd24-6510380b7c35" UUID_SUB="b2664b6b-fae1-76e1-845e-50faa4dfa13d" LABEL="blackbox.qwarx.com:Rust" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sdc: UUID="653729f4-efb2-af46-dd24-6510380b7c35" UUID_SUB="e9defcaf-3cba-2337-17a9-bd247317ecfe" LABEL="blackbox.qwarx.com:Rust" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sdd: UUID="653729f4-efb2-af46-dd24-6510380b7c35" UUID_SUB="121f8be1-5ab4-9de0-238d-6ba64aae8c00" LABEL="blackbox.qwarx.com:Rust" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sda: UUID="653729f4-efb2-af46-dd24-6510380b7c35" UUID_SUB="dbbffe6d-dae0-31dd-a310-913a1cc8a8e8" LABEL="blackbox.qwarx.com:Rust" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/mapper/SSD-CentOS7_Root: LABEL="CentOS7_Root" UUID="aa48bf01-c012-4e54-806b-e0a341d548c2" TYPE="xfs" 
/dev/md125: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="EFI" UUID="F61A-994A" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/md124: UUID="RUXdND-W4mD-lXdF-YWMk-J7yY-w50S-zgdxOh" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/SSD-home: UUID="4031d5d7-dc64-49c4-9ecc-b139709a96ab" TYPE="xfs" 
/dev/mapper/SSD-MD_Journal: UUID="653729f4-efb2-af46-dd24-6510380b7c35" UUID_SUB="b504320e-e625-30cd-0270-77b9b63e2482" LABEL="blackbox.qwarx.com:Rust" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/mapper/SSD-Containers: UUID="c9cd5afb-bdd9-4561-bdac-d3793a7b0c1c" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/Rust-Rescued: LABEL="Rescued" UUID="9c17d2d8-700c-49c2-98fe-1fb1dde733c6" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/Rust-Microserver: LABEL="Microserver" UUID="242d2ddf-0759-4346-a545-8df042af5ebe" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/Rust-NAS: LABEL="NAS" UUID="a37875cf-1f5c-46aa-a825-4204cc98e4c9" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/Rust-Video: LABEL="Video" UUID="92b9e7e9-874f-433b-aa72-0465546986b7" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/Rust-Dxxxxx: LABEL="Dxxxxx" UUID="689947c7-7e62-4a3c-a871-59ea923c4dcf" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/Rust-Backups: LABEL="Backups" UUID="9d0534b2-a545-410f-a9d4-eda4f9836bfb" TYPE="ext4"
```

Comment: Can you please add the output of `blkid` to the question?

Comment: Does it work if you do a `pvscan --cache major:minor` on the device major and minor device numbers of /dev/SSD/Rust_Cache?

Comment: Please post the content of `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`.

Comment: Thank you for adding to details to your question, still it is not possible to exactly locate the issue. Having an assumption it would be helpful the have a look into the config file
`egrep -v "^(\s+)?#|^$" /etc/lvm/lvm.conf`

Comment: Further `lvdisplay /dev/mapper/SSD-Rust_Cache` would be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I fixed it!

It was really simple. I knew that **volume groups** have an available flag, which you can change with:

```
vgchange -ay /dev/VG
```

But I didn't know until now that **logical volumes** also have such a flag, and it can be set by the user.

As with volume groups, it seems that sometimes this flag is persisted after the reason for unavailability has disappeared. So I was able to make the Photos LV accessible like this, with no errors, and then mount it:

```
lvchange -ay /dev/Rust/Photos
```

I did find and change the following setting in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`, as it seemed that it might be relevant to this particular device not activating automatically, so that may have fixed the underlying issue/root cause:

```
    # Configuration option devices/scan_lvs.
    # Scan LVM LVs for layered PVs, allowing LVs to be used as PVs.
    # When 1, LVM will detect PVs layered on LVs, and caution must be
    # taken to avoid a host accessing a layered VG that may not belong
    # to it, e.g. from a guest image. This generally requires excluding
    # the LVs with device filters. Also, when this setting is enabled,
    # every LVM command will scan every active LV on the system (unless
    # filtered), which can cause performance problems on systems with
    # many active LVs. When this setting is 0, LVM will not detect or
    # use PVs that exist on LVs, and will not allow a PV to be created on
    # an LV. The LVs are ignored using a built in device filter that
    # identifies and excludes LVs.
    scan_lvs = 1
```

Comment: I'm happy to read you solved it. Thank you for sharing, did learn something new from your post.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried booting with a repair disk or livecd like knoppix to see if you can mount that way? How about booting into your previous kernel from grub boot menu?